# grouping list by N to new tab[]

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

Hi I'm new in linq and c#.

I need to grouping list of client objects by N and replace it to tab.
For example
list of:
*user1
user2
(...)
userN*

and I want to receive `List<Client>[] tabOfClients` with smaller lists inside like:

> tab[0] - list of user1 to userN
>
> tab[1] - list of userN+1 to user 2N
>
> (...)

when **N=3**

I find way to grouping every 3rd objects but its not my target
somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of banding and grouping:

```
var groupedUsers = users.Select((e,i) => new{ Index=Math.Floor(i/n),User=e})
                    .GroupBy(g => g.Index);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/GZORR50968

To explain:

`users` is the list of objects you want to group
 `users.Select((e,i) => new{ Index=Math.Floor(i/n),User=e})` projects that list into a list of anonymous objects with 2 properties:

- `Index` is the result of dividing the index of the item by the number of items you want in a group
- `User` is the original object

At this point you'll end up with a list such as

- Index=0, User=a
- Index=0, User=b
- Index=0, User=c
- Index=1, User=d
- Index=1, User=e
- Index=1, User=f
- etc

Then you can just `GroupBy` that `Index` to get a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Do a loop for each multiple of N and inside the loop create a new list for each tab[x] and populate the list with appropriate users.

Answer (score 0):

here's a solution using `Dictionary<int,List<string>>`

```
   List<string> list = new List<string>{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7"};

   var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

   for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i+=3)
       dict[i] = list.Where((s,index) => index >= i && index < i+3).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

I dunno why you would want to do this through linq, but it's doable:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var o = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => x.ToString());
    int i = 0;
    var groups = o.GroupBy(x => i++ / 3);
    foreach (var g in groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", g));
    }
}
```

We are using `i` to count how many times something is being hit and to group.

Note that this may not work on all LINQ sources, but for simplistic collections it will work okay.

I do suggest you simply foreach and use that method.

Comment: It is doable, but that's not the way to do it!

Comment: I agree - the .Select() way is better (though somewhat less efficient - not that I think that OP cares since they are using LINQ anyway).